# Python3 String to number

Tags: python-3.x

I want to some special string change to 1 , and the all of others(except 1) to 0

My code is here

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : list('abcdefghi')})
df.name.replace({"a" : 1, "b" :1}, inplace = True)
df['name'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x:0 if x!='1' else int(x))
df
```

but excute above code, all things are 0.
How can I get code what I want?

Thanks for reading`

Comment: I didnt get your question. But what i understand is there is a string lets a= "abcdefgh" and you want some letters to be 0 and some to 1 correct?

Comment: Well you've replaced them into **int** `1` and in `apply` you are checking if any of them are **str** `1`.

Comment: Thank you coment Chris.. I`m beginner ..and I`m not good at English..  Wolud you show me right code?

Comment: akhilpathania28 - right, that is example, in Dataframe columns I had change some special string to 1 using replace. and now I want to change the others(in column, except 1)  0. .. Can you understand? sry I`m poor at English

Comment: use `df['name'].apply(lambda x:0 if x!=1 else int(x))`

Comment: Rakesh, Oh I got it!! Thank you sooooo much

Comment: Flag is bad things?

Comment: You can also try `df['name'].map({"a" : 1, "b" :1}).fillna(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your code is absolutely right except some typo.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : list('abcdefghi')})
df.name.replace({"a" : 1, "b" :1}, inplace = True)
df['name'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x:0 if x!=1 else int(x))
df
```

So change this it will solve the problem.